# How to fire a webhook in Azure DevOps when a comment is updated

Tags: azure-devops, webhooks

I have some webhooks in place to replicate bugs from our back-end system for end user support. When we get a support call and an incident is created in that system, and specific conditions are met, it gets pushed to ADO and a bug is created. When work is done on that bug, and the details are added to it in ADO, the webhook fires and updates the record in the support tool via it's API. No big deal there. The problem I'm facing is with comments. When a comment is created it fires the web hook as it should, but if I go into a bug and edit an existing comment, the change does not trigger the webhook.  (It doesn't require a save action on the ADO workitem at all. Could that be forced to occur on updates to existing comments?)

We are using tags to determine if the webhook is triggered.

I don't see a way to accomplish this. Has anyone figured out how to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested and could reproduce your problem.

When adding a new comment for the work item, it fires the web hook. But the same issue as yours, when updating the existing comment, you just need to click the "update" button, this action could not fire the web hook

This seems to be a function issue and need to be point out via: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=problem. I suggest you could create a feedback ticket to report this.

Comment: Looks like someone already created a ticket about this 1,5y ago https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Webhook-event-payload-for-workitem-does/1328283

Comment: Yes, I have checked this link. It was reported 1.5 year ago. Let's vote and leave a comment.